# Migration of on-prem Nexus nuget Host to azure Artifacts(Azure DevOps server)

Tags: nuget, migration, nexus, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-services

I have a project to migrate all on-prem nexus nugets to azure Artifact(azure DevOps service(VSTS)).
is there any tool available to help on this matter. On-prem nexus contains our own customize nugets and can only be available via company VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming nexus on-prem is a private repository, as such there is no direct way from ADO to communicate with private repositories.

So i guess there are 2 options to do this.

1)Download the packages locally and then publish to Azure artifacts. You can install these packages directly in CI pipelines.

You can use below MS link to do the same

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows

2)Make use of Self Hosted Agents.

Comment: What do you want to achive this via self hosted agents?